# Is it possible program GPIO PINs using Microsoft MakeCode?

Tags: rpi.gpio

It is possible to run Microsoft [Make Code](https://maker.makecode.com/raspberry-pi) on a Raspberry Pi. But it looks like I can select a bunch of boards but not a Pi.

Is it possible to program the GPIO pins on the Pi by running Make Code on the Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi is not a supported board.

I have no idea if it can be a supported board as all the other boards seem to be microcontroller based.

I suppose you could try adding the Pi as a new board by following the documented procedure.

https://maker.makecode.com/boards/add-a-new-board

Answer (score 0):

Though not directly as a hardware device/microcontroller(like the micro:bit), there still are some possibilities for the Raspberry Pi(RPi) through MakeCode Arcade(MCA):

- You can install an official boot image to download(as native .elf files or special USB drive mapped .uf2 files) and run your own MCA games/programs on, at least, the RPi 3A and Zero,
- You can download and run native .elf files of your MCA games/programs on most RPi models running RPi OS and probably other Linux distros(you might need a launcher, like McAirpos, to properly quit programs and return to the console, and get support for more and EV_ABS type game controllers)
- Here you get access to:

  - GPIOs as input
  - The serial interface as output to an external board(maybe also input)
  - Keyboard and EV_KEY controllers for up to 4 players
  - Graphics display and sound/music output
- At the time being, "the GPIOs are not supported(as output) from user code."
- Though, "the runtime itself has access to them...". I am not sure if this means that it would be possible for the community to program an extension that would make the GPIOs also available in MCA as outputs.

Lastly, there's BlockTalky, with support for the GrovePi and BrickPi shields and sensors and actuators, and music on the RPi:
https://www.playfulcomputation.group/blockytalky.html

Sources:

- https://forum.makecode.com/t/raspberry-pi-gpio-output/2492
- https://arcade.makecode.com/hardware/raspberry-pi

Update 2021.11.17:
The RP2040/Pico board now seems to be available on https://maker.makecode.com (Misc boards).
https://github.com/microsoft/pxt-maker/search?q=rp2040&type=commits

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/114639)

Comment: Sorry, @Chenmunka; I was being lazy. Better now?